# ES6 or uglify minify maven plugin without node js

Tags: javascript, java, maven, ecmascript-6, maven-plugin

I try to find maven plugin to minify Javascript files with ES6 code. I tried minify-maven-plugin 1.7.6 but I think it doesn't support ES6 (error syntax on default parameter in function).   I tried also some plugin to uglify ES6 to es5 but it doesn't work too, so maybe sb had that same problem. Eventually please some short instruction for fronted-maven-plugin how to do it by web pack or babel, but I don't sure I can use node js.

Configuration minify-maven-plugin :

```
<executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-minify</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>minify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <cssSourceDir>static/css</cssSourceDir>
                                    <cssSourceIncludes>
                                        <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>
                                    </cssSourceIncludes>
                                    <jsSourceDir>static/js</jsSourceDir>
                                    <jsSourceIncludes>
                                        <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                                        <jsSourceInclude>legacy/**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                                    </jsSourceIncludes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
```

Error in minfiy-maven-plugin :

```
[ERROR] missing ) after formal parameters at lazy-module-test.js line 1572:29
                function mojaFunkcja(x = 1, y, z) {
                                         ^

[ERROR] missing } after function body at lazy-module-test.js line 1572:29
                function mojaFunkcja(x = 1, y, z) {
                                     ^
```

Configuration frontend-maven-plugin:

```
<executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install grunt grunt-cli grunt-contrib-uglify</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>grunt build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>grunt</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v6.9.1</nodeVersion>
                        </configuration>
```

Error in frontend-maven-plugin:

```
[INFO]   message: 'Unexpected token operator «=», expected punc «,»',
[INFO]   filename: '../../../../../../../src/main/webapp/static/js/lazy/module-test/controllers/testCtrl.js',
[INFO]   line: 150,
[INFO]   col: 27,
[INFO]   pos: 4283 }
```

Line 150:

```
function mojaFunkcja(x = 1, y, z) {
```

Comment: How does this relate to Java?

Comment: Some maven plugins needs to compiler in Java 8 and whole project is in Java. Sth like extra info

Comment: frontend-maven-plugin will automatically download and use node and npm as part of the build for you if you are worried about Java developers not having these tools. Google for 'uglify maven java', or similar, to find Maven plugins that use the Nashorn scripting engine shipped with Java SE 8 (so don't need Node, but may be slower)

Answer (score 0):

This Maven plugin works very well for me: https://github.com/SpyrosPac/frontend-files-uglifier

It can minify JS and CSS files using Uglify.js and CSSO respectively. Both are executed via Rhino, so Node is not required.

Performance is quite alright, especially when you enable the option to only compress modified resources.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>` under your plugin configuration. By default, `minify-maven-plugin` uses `YUI compressor` which is not ES6 compliant. But, another supported Javascript engine i.e `Google Closure` is ES6 compliant. A working sample entry from `pom.xml` is given below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>minify-resources-exec</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <jsSourceDir>app/${minifyJsSrcDir}</jsSourceDir>
            <jsSourceIncludes>**/*.js</jsSourceIncludes>
            <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <jsTargetDir>${minifyJsSrcDir}</jsTargetDir>
            <jsFinalFile>${minifyJsFinalFile}</jsFinalFile>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
            <goal>minify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>              
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For more info, please refer to: https://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/minify-mojo.html